# RESTLET GAE ECLIPSE initializate method

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, initialization, restlet, init

I'm developing an application with Restlet, GAE and Eclipse. Oks, I got this:

public class MainRestletApplication extends Application {

```
public MainRestletApplication()
{
//init code?
} 


@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    router.attach("/v1/mainstatus",MainStatus.class);
    router.attach("/v1/game/{id}/result",GameResult.class);

    return router;
}
```

}

and this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.MainRestletApplication
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<!-- Catch all requests -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

Well, where can I put a method to init the Web Service, ergo, some code to init some data only when the app starts (one time), not when the first call coming.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

wether you use Restlet or not, AppEngine or not, you can setup a context listener in any servlet environment in your web.xml like this :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        example.ServletContextExample
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

And implement this ;

```
public class ServletContextExample implements ServletContextListener{
    ServletContext context;
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        System.out.println("Context Created");
        context = contextEvent.getServletContext();
        // set variable to servlet context
        context.setAttribute("TEST", "TEST_VALUE");
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        context = contextEvent.getServletContext();
        System.out.println("Context Destroyed");
    }
}
```

When your instance on GAE is started, the init code will be executed, before a call is processed; on the other hand, a new instance is most likely started because a call must be processed. chicken and egg story...

Answer (score 0):

You can override the start() method of your com.example.MainRestletApplication class for this purpose. Its lifecycle is synchronized with the wrapper RestletServlet.