# Restlet: Initialization code before application start

Tags: java, jetty, restlet, restlet-2.0, jetty-9

How can I run java code before first request arived to server (before the application)?

Should I define something in web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706084/restlet-gae-eclipse-initializate-method)
- [Example 2](http://www.deadcoderising.com/execute-code-on-webapp-startup-and-shutdown-using-servletcontextlistener/)

[servlet dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/3.0-alpha-1)